# mplayer SVN r34540 update

Tags: 12.04, mplayer, smplayer

How can I update my mplayer to latest version? I am using mplayer integrated with smplayer.

Comment: How did you install (s)mplayer? From source? From USC?

Comment: I installed from http://smplayer.sourceforge.net/en/downloads

Comment: That is not answering the question. It shows -both- options: a PPA for USC and source files.

Comment: oh sorry...so i downloaded by adding ppa.

Answer (score 0):

I use this ppa: https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/mplayer-test

The daily svn builds are stable and bug free for me (archlinux stable repo contains such version), while the repo version contains some bug that I cannot stand.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this guide might be your answer:

Build the svn MPlayer under the latest Ubuntu release

http://www.andrews-corner.org/ubuntu/mplayer.html

Some compiling involved but the guide has a simple set of code boxes to paste into your terminal screen...